# How to upload an image to Firebase? Is it possible?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I'm tring to upload an image to firebase cloud function. I think that I have read the whole of post about this and I can't get a solution.

I have used "formidable.IncomingForm()", "multer" and "busboy" but noone is working.

I understood that I had to use busboy.  I would like to share my last code with this library.

```
app.post('/',function(req,res) {
    var busboy = new Busboy({headers: req.headers});
    var files = 0, finished = false;
    busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        console.log('File [' + fieldname + ']: filename: ' + filename);
        console.log("Uploading: " + filename);
        ++files;
      //  const temp = os.tmpdir();
      //  var path = temp.writeFileSync(file);
       let path=os.tmpdir()+"/"+filename
       let p=fs.writeFileSync(path,file)
       console.log(path)
        var fstream = fs.createWriteStream(path);
        fstream.on('finish', function () {
            if (--files === 0) {
                // Upload a local file to a new file to be created in your bucket.
                bucket.upload(path,function (err, file) {

                    if (!err) {
                        console.log("Uploaded: " + path);
                        res.json({
                            uploaded: true,
                            created_at: new Date().getTime(),
                            filename: filename,
                            mimeType: mimetype
                        });
                    }else{
                        console.error("err: " + err);
                        var error = new ErrorResponse(400);
                        error.errors+=err;
                        res.json(error);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        file.pipe(fstream);
    })
    req.pipe(busboy);
})
```

This code upload files successfully in my local server but not in Firebase Cloud functions.

My post request is:
[image: My post request is:]

The problem is that the function "busboy.on('file'..." is never execute

Comment: where are you trying to store the image?
If I am not getting it wrong, you are using firebase functions to upload an image to firebase storage. is it correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly! But the problem is with the firabase-function because it does not get the file. In others words, the function "busboy.on" is never executed

Comment: Yes! Only an image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I am a noob with `busboy`. I'd stick to the most popular library `multer`.

Using `multer's` in-memory storage, upload the image as a buffer. And use that buffer to upload image to the bucket.

Try the snippet below:

```js
var multer = require('multer')
// using the in-memory storage
var upload = multer()

// use the same paramter you are using for uploading from postman
app.post('/', upload.single('file'), function(req, res) {
  const fileBuff = req.file.buffer
  const fileName = req.file.filename
  const mimeType = req.file.mimetype


  const file = myBucket.file(fileName);

  file.save(fileBuff)
    .then(success => {
      res.json({
        uploaded: true,
        created_at: new Date().getTime(),
        filename: fileName,
        mimeType: mimeType
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error("err: " + err);
      var error = new ErrorResponse(400);
      error.errors += err;
      res.json(error);
    })
})
```

Comment: My problem is not with "temp file", because that line is never executed. The same happend with multer and formidable.IncomingForm(). Locally it works but in Firebase-cloud function not. When I execute your example: "req.file" is empty eventhough I send a file

Comment: It was working. I don't known why jaja. I have one more doubt. The variable  "fileBuff". How do I have to fill it??

Comment: Multer put it in req.file.buffer. you don't have to do anything.

Comment: The problem is that I have the following error:
TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;buffer&#39; of undefined
I deleted this line by mistake and this work but the file was uploaded empty.

Comment: I add some changes that this code need to work! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why Harroon Khan's solution doesn't work with your current test is because you're not actually sending a file to your endpoint using postman, you're only sending the **filename**.

This is problematic, since your endpoint will only work in your local development environment.

You should try his solution when sending an actual file with postman. Here's a little screenshot that shows you how to toggle it:

Uploading a file using Postman

[image]

Comment: I was using "File" as type obviously

Answer (score 0):

This code work for me! I don't known why but I have to write a file, then read it and finally, upload the data That I read to the storage

```
ex.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  const busboy = new Busboy({
    headers: req.headers
  });
  const tmpdir = os.tmpdir();

  // This object will accumulate all the fields, keyed by their name
  const fields = {};
  // This object will accumulate all the uploaded files, keyed by their name.
  const uploads = {};
  // This code will process each non-file field in the form.
  busboy.on('field', (fieldname, val) => {
    // TODO(developer): Process submitted field values here
    console.log(`Processed field ${fieldname}: ${val}.`);
    fields[fieldname] = val;
  });
  const fileWrites = [];
  // This code will process each file uploaded.
  busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename) => {
    // Note: os.tmpdir() points to an in-memory file system on GCF
    // Thus, any files in it must fit in the instance's memory.
    console.log(`Processed file ${filename}`);
    const filepath = path.join(tmpdir, filename);
    console.log("PATH: "+filepath)
    uploads[fieldname] = filepath;
    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filepath);
    file.pipe(writeStream);
    // File was processed by Busboy; wait for it to be written to disk.
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      file.on('end', () => {
        writeStream.end();
      });
      writeStream.on('finish', resolve);
      writeStream.on('error', reject);
    });
    fileWrites.push(promise);
  });

  // Triggered once all uploaded files are processed by Busboy.
  // We still need to wait for the disk writes (saves) to complete.
  busboy.on('finish', () => {
    Promise.all(fileWrites).then(() => {
      // TODO(developer): Process saved files here
      for (const name in uploads) {
        const file = uploads[name];
        let data = fs.readFileSync(uploads[name]);
        const filetoGCF = bucket.file("file-name");
        filetoGCF.save(data)
          .then(success => {
            res.json({
              uploaded: true,
              created_at: new Date().getTime(),
              filename: 'file-name',
            });

          })
        fs.unlinkSync(file);
      }
    }).catch((err)=>{
      res.json({
        uploaded: false,
        error: err,
      });
    });
  });

  busboy.end(req.rawBody);
})
```

Thanks Haroon Khan for your help!